# XML node: Creating namespaced attribute displays null string as node value in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I’ve created a root node with namespace prefix ‘example’ as follows:

```js
var stringXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>'
    + '<example:root xmlns:example="http://example.com"></example:root>';
var xmlDoc = jQuery.parseXML(stringXML);
```

Then I created a child node under same namespace as follows:

```js
var tag = xmlDoc.createElementNS('http://example.com', 'example:tag');
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://example.com', 'root')[0];
x.appendChild(tag);
```

I want to create a namespaced attribute to `tag` node without specifying nodevalue.

```js
var attr = xmlDoc.createAttributeNS('http://sample.com', 'sample:sampleNode');
tag.setAttributeNode(attr);
```

I’m expecting an output like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example:root xmlns:example="http://example.com">
    <example:tag xmlns:sample="http://sample.com"/>
</example:root>
```

But in my XML, attribute with null string is displayed as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example:root xmlns:example="http://example.com">
    <example:tag xmlns:sample="http://sample.com" sample:sampleNode=""/>
</example:root>
```

Could anyone can give a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. You add an empty attribute, but you are surprised to see an empty attribute, and you would expect no attribute instead? Then don't add the attribute.